# How to pass variable to piped part of command

Tags: powershell, variables

I have this command and I'm trying to push the name of the user into the -ForwardingSmtpAddress parameter. But I'm still getting errors.

```
Get-Mailbox username | Set-Mailbox -ForwardingSmtpAddress ("smtp:" + ($_).Identity + "@domain.com")
```

Could you please help how to specify the Identity in the second part of command? Thanks!

EDIT: Actually, It seems like the `$_` variable is empty.. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `Identity` referring to?

Comment: It is the parameter of Get-Mailbox cmdlet - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685(v=exchg.160).aspx  It should be username of the Get-Mailbox result.

Comment: I understand that. What value do you want to use for it? `sAMAccountName` of account? In other words: What do you want for that part of the forwarding SMTP address to be?

Comment: try `("smtp:" + $_.alias + "@domain.com")`

Comment: I want the ForwardingSmtpAddress  to be "smtp: _Identity_ @domain.com". Same value is stored also in Id and Alias parameters

Comment: @BenH `(Get-Mailbox username).Identity` returns value correctly

Comment: @Avshalom Does not work, it gives empty string. Result: You can't forward email to 'smtp:@domain.com' because the address format isn't correct.

Comment: This might help try this:    -ForwardingSmtpAddress "smtp:$($_.Identity)@domain.com"

Comment: After all I solved it using foreach..